# mootools in virtuemart

Tags: joomla, mootools, virtuemart

I am trying to use mootools in my virtuemart module.

Basically the module must be able to display an image slider components with the snapshots of products

Can any one tell me how to go about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Without more specific information, it sounds like virtuemart might already do what you're asking for?  If I remember correctly, I think this [JM/VM ecommerce bundle](http://cb.virtuemart.net/cb/displayDocument/VirtueMart_1.1.4_eCommerce_Bunde_Joomla_1.5.14.tgz?doc_id=4246) has a product slider enabled by default on the homepage -- have a look at that and see if it suits your needs.